# Android SpeechRecognizer: cancel() and stopListening() being completely ignored (but only at Android 9 and 10)

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-speech-api

I have a project using RecognitionListener written in Kotlin. The speech-to-text function is a success but there are some problems after testing it at an Android 9 or 10 device.

After I start listening with startListening() function, it actually stops after some time of inactivity (within 1 second). I added some functions so the user can stop with a button and have the results, or cancel with a button and ignore the results. It worked pretty well testing at an Android 8 device. But when I tested at an Android 10 device, it never worked. (tested on Android 9 too and different devices with Android 10... same problem)

Here is the VoiceRecognition speech-to-text class code:

```
package com.primelan.primebot.botVoiceRecognition.voice_recognition

import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.RecognitionListener
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class VoiceRecognition(private val activity: Activity, language: String = "pt_BR") : RecognitionListener {

    private val AudioLogTag = "AudioInput"

    var voiceRecognitionIntentHandler: VoiceRecognitionIntentHandler? = null
    var voiceRecognitionOnResultListener: VoiceRecognitionOnResultListener? = null //Must have this
    var voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger: VoiceRecognitionLayoutChanger? = null

    var isListening = false

    private var enableResult = true
    private val intent: Intent
    private var speech: SpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity)

    init {
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this)

        intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        intent.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
        )
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language)
    }

    //It is important to put this function inside a clickListener
    fun listen(): Boolean {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO), 1)
            return false
        }

        speech.startListening(intent)

        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "startListening")

        return true
    }

    //Use this if you want to stop listening but still get recognition results
    fun endListening(){
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "stopListening")

        speech.stopListening()
        isListening = false
    }

    fun cancelListening(){
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "cancelListening")

        speech.cancel()
        voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.endListeningChangeLayout()
        isListening = false
    }

    override fun onReadyForSpeech(p0: Bundle?) {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onReadyForSpeech")

        voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.startListeningChangeLayout()
        isListening = true
    }

    override fun onRmsChanged(p0: Float) {
//        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: $p0")
//        progressBar.setProgress((Int) p0)
    }

    override fun onBufferReceived(p0: ByteArray?) {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onBufferReceived: $p0")
    }

    override fun onPartialResults(p0: Bundle?) {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onPartialResults")
    }

    override fun onEvent(p0: Int, p1: Bundle?) {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onEvent")
    }

    override fun onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onBeginningOfSpeech")
    }

    override fun onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onEndOfSpeech")

        voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.endListeningChangeLayout()
        isListening = false

        enableResult = true
    }

    override fun onError(p0: Int) {
        speech.cancel()
        val errorMessage = getErrorText(p0)
        Log.d(AudioLogTag, "FAILED: $errorMessage")
        voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.endListeningChangeLayout()
        isListening = false
    }

    override fun onResults(p0: Bundle?) {
        if(enableResult) {
            enableResult = false
            Log.i(AudioLogTag, "onResults")

            val results: ArrayList<String> =
                p0?.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION) as ArrayList<String>

            val voiceIntent: Int? = voiceRecognitionIntentHandler?.getIntent(results[0])
            if (voiceIntent != null && voiceIntent != 0) {
                voiceRecognitionIntentHandler?.handle(voiceIntent)
                return
            }

            voiceRecognitionOnResultListener!!.onResult(results[0])
        }
    }

    private fun getErrorText(errorCode: Int): String {
        val message: String
        when (errorCode) {
            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO -> message = "Audio recording error"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT -> message = "Client side error"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS -> message = "Insufficient permissions"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK -> message = "Network error"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT -> message = "Network timeout"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH -> message = "No match"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY -> message = "RecognitionService busy"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER -> message = "Error from server"

            SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT -> message = "No speech input"

            else -> message = "Didn't understand, please try again."
        }
        return message
    }

    //Use it in your overriden onPause function.
    fun onPause() {
        voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.endListeningChangeLayout()
        isListening = false

        speech.cancel()
        Log.i(AudioLogTag, "pause")
    }

    //Use it in your overriden onDestroy function.
    fun onDestroy() {
        speech.destroy()
    }
}
```

As you can see, the functions that I mentioned are `endListening()` and `cancelListening()`. When those functions are called, you can actually see the Log, but the cancel() or the stopListening() won't have any effects if the current device is using android 9 or 10. Even the line `voiceRecognitionLayoutChanger?.endListeningChangeLayout()` from `cancelListening()` is executed and brings the desired results (changes a layout inside the app).

Is there a problem with android.speech library? Or... is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Having the same problem. I too created an issue in the android issue tracker and provided an demo APK and video. Let's see if it gets resolved.

Comment: @erksch Good to see that I'm not the only one. Can you share the issue (link) with us?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158198432

Comment: Problem is on Android side, waiting on the fix...